# controller action not found MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

In my view I have this ActionLink

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Contract", new { id = Model.ContractId }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm" })
```

I have an Edit View and a `ContractController`

In the `ContractController` I have this action method

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditPost(int id, ContractViewModel vm)
{
  ... code here
```

at runtime when  click the actionlink (Contract\Edit\33)  I get a

> 404 error Edit was not found on controller Controllers.Contract.ContractController

can anyone see where Im going wrong here ?

Comment: Is there an EditPost with a `[HttpGet]' attribute. As the action link will generate the link for a Get Request, not a Post Request. Or just an Edit Action Method. As it doesn't need to explicitly say its a HttpGet

Comment: Ive changed the method signature to this   [ActionName("Edit")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int id, ContractCreationViewModel vm)
        {    but im gettng this error now   the required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Comment: This might help you understand the process a little better. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/examining-the-edit-methods-and-edit-view

Comment: A link makes a GET, not a POST. Remove the `[HttpPost]` and `ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attributesand remove the `ContractViewModel vm` parameter from the method

Answer (score 0):

code should be like below to access an action method from the link you created

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Edit")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditPost(int id)
{
```